# How to Deselect Filter Using Isotope?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

Is there any way for me to insert a code in isotope that lets me deselect one filter without deselecting the others?  Here's the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 // init Isotope
 var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'
 });

 $('.shuffle-button').on('click', function() {
  $grid.isotope('shuffle');
 });

 $('.unshuffle-button').on('click', function() {
  $grid.isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' })
 });

 // store filter for each group
 var filters = {};

 $('.filters').on('click', '.button', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   // get group key
   var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
   var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
   // set filter for group
   filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
   // combine filters
   var filterValue = concatValues(filters);
   // set filter for Isotope
   $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
 });

 // change is-checked class on buttons
 $('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
   var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
   $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
     $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
     $(this).addClass('is-checked');
   });
 });

});

// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues(obj) {
 var value = '';
 for (var prop in obj) {
   value += obj[ prop ];
 }
 return value;
}

</script>
```

Here's a sample of the html:

```
<div class="button-group" data-filter-group="age">
<h1>AGE</h1>
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">all</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".10s">teens</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".20s">20s</button>
</div>

<div class="button-group" data-filter-group="gender">
<h1>GENDER</h1>
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">all</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".male">male</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".female">female</button>
</div>

<div class="button-group" data-filter-group="race">
<h1>ETHNICITY</h1>
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">all</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".poc">poc</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".white">white</button>
</div>
```

Say I have 20s, male, and poc selected, but I decide I want to deselect male and select female instead.  For some reason, it won't let me do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain more about your issue?

Comment: @Just code No problem!  So [this](http://perdomoassists.tumblr.com/fc-directory) is the directory I'm working on.  I have ethnicities separated into categories (black, white, latino, etc).  If I'm searching for someone that falls under two different categories (black and east asian), I'll click "all" under both categories.  But I was wondering if there was a way for me to deselect a category (ex: asian) by clicking on it, the same I did to select it.